# Jenkins build job does not finish even though it was successful

Tags: java, jenkins

I have created a Jenkins job that builds, deploys, and starts a JBoss server. According to the Jenkins build job console the JBoss server has started successfully, but the actual Jenkins build job still does not finish. It just hangs there. Any ideas on what to do with this?

Comment: How are you starting the JBoss server ? Is it waiting for JBoss to exit ?

Comment: run.jar is executed. hmm I guess the command prompt will remain open. Nohup could be used, but even in that case I guess the command prompt remains open?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not sent any configuration information I can just guess that you do not stop your jboss in the end of your build, so maven just does not know it should terminate.

If you are running JBoss in order to run integration tests your executions configuration should be similar to mine:

```
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-jetty</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                        <daemon>true</daemon>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-jetty</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
```

Please pay attention on phase `post-integration-test` where I stop the server.

If however you want to run JBoss and terminate you probably should use `<forkMode>true</forkMode>` into configuration.

Comment: I do not stop the server at the end. Ok that is probably something I should do, no need to keep it open forever :)

Comment: actually this case was not closed just yet. I added an ant target to stop the server afterwards, but it still hangs on completion of the start server target. I looked if Jenkins could parse the logs to see whether a "success" statement is found in the logs, but apparently no such is present.